# php-fpm not loading same extensions php-cli is

Tags: php, centos, fpm

Using php-5.4. I'm trying to load 'oci8.so' to access the function `oci_connect`.  When in command line, I can access said function fine. But (after reloading, restarting, and reloading) php-fpm REFUSES to load the extension.

`php -r 'print_r(get_loaded_extensions());` lists `oci8`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => zlib
    [7] => bz2
    [8] => calendar
    [9] => ctype
    [10] => hash
    [11] => filter
    [12] => ftp
    [13] => gettext
    [14] => gmp
    [15] => SPL
    [16] => iconv
    [17] => pcntl
    [18] => readline
    [19] => Reflection
    [20] => session
    [21] => standard
    [22] => shmop
    [23] => SimpleXML
    [24] => sockets
    [25] => exif
    [26] => tokenizer
    [27] => xml
    [28] => curl
    [29] => fileinfo
    [30] => json
    [31] => oci8
    [32] => Phar
    [33] => zip
    [34] => mhash
)
```

However `curl localhost/extensions.php` reads

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => zlib
    [7] => bz2
    [8] => calendar
    [9] => ctype
    [10] => hash
    [11] => filter
    [12] => ftp
    [13] => gettext
    [14] => gmp
    [15] => SPL
    [16] => iconv
    [17] => Reflection
    [18] => session
    [19] => standard
    [20] => shmop
    [21] => SimpleXML
    [22] => sockets
    [23] => exif
    [24] => tokenizer
    [25] => xml
    [26] => cgi-fcgi
    [27] => curl
    [28] => fileinfo
    [29] => json
    [30] => Phar
    [31] => zip
    [32] => mhash
    // missing oci8
    // and also missing 'pcntl'??
)
```

Both the fpm and cli are reading the exact same `php.ini`. I have check and tested.

Nothing at all in any error logs.

Comment: How specifically have you checked that fpm/cli php.ini were the same?

Comment: "Using php-5.4" WHY? NO! Don't do that. Anyway, probably a php.ini file is getting included in one SAPI and not the other. Check with `php -i` compared to output on web from `phpinfo()`. Watch for "Loaded Configuration File" and "Additional .ini files parsed" in each.

Comment: It's for a client and of course they force me to use outdated equipment.

Comment: Then make them hire you to do an upgrade! No excuse for running such old versions. At least 5.6 just went EOL last year.

Comment: Again. both `php -i` and the fpm's `phpinfo()` point to `/etc/php.ini`. That is where `extension=oci8.so` is located.

Comment: @miken32 I guess until a better answer comes along I can only blame the version.

Answer (score 2):

Well not sure it is related but this happened to me on "Amazon Linux 2 AMI" so I guess could apply to "CentOS" too.

Long story short I installed composer and other php stuff.

```
[zzzz@stageOpenID /etc/httpd/sites-enabled]$ php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.2.30

System => Linux stageOpenID 4.14.177-139.254.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 7 18:48:23 UTC 2020 x86_64
Build Date => May  5 2020 18:04:39
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed =>
```

So far so good.

And now to the web.

From phpinfo.php:

```
PHP Version: 7.2.30 
System: Linux stageOpenID 4.14.177-139.254.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 7 18:48:23 UTC 2020 x86_64
Build Date: May 5 2020 18:06:20
Server API: FPM/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support: disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed
```

But the lists are different.

Why? Simply because after the yum installation I restarted httpd but I forgot to restart php-fpm, so php-cli got the new modules and php-fpm didn't.

So, don't forget to:

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you have installed PHP FPM but, On Debian CLI and FPM use different ini files try:

```
   php -i | grep php.ini
```

Mines is /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

and

```
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Mine is /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those are troubleshooting steps, not an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, you'll be able to comment on any post. Until then, please refrain from answering with questions or comments!